# multiple CRUD APIs in single Controller is Bad design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

We are Automating provisioning of Azure Resources.We have a controller file named AzureSQLServerController which takes care of all the CRUD operations in Azure SQL Server.

We have the following APIs:

Create SQL Server- POST 
modify sql server-Put

Now for SQL server firewall rules -in the AzureSQLServerController.cs  itslef.

CreateFirewallRule -POST
ModifySQLServerFirewallRule -PUT

The question here is this: Having multiple CRUD operation APIs in a single controller file is Problematic? Keeping multping POST APIs will make it difficult for the Client to consume the APIs?Cant I resolve the problem using "Config routing" and using the "Action name" for the APIs? Or Should I create different controllers for every CRUD operations for example AzureSQLServerController and AzureSQLServerFirewallController?

Comment: Get Fiddler and play around with the management portal. You will see how Microsoft has implemented this. The question is heavily off-topics because it is primarily opinion based! Not to mention that it is not about code at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea, and probably you'll face problems with Url routing.

Some tips:

1-study a little about restful services granularity
2-take a look at Attribute Routing Nuget (unless you are using ASPNET MVC 5) http://attributerouting.net/

This nugget will save you many hours with routing. (and that's why you should separate in more controllers)